# Do SQL Server partition switch on partition A while a long running query is consuming partition B

Tags: sql-server, locking, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm currently looking for a method to improve the overall ability to ingest and consume data at the same time in an analytical environment (data warehouse). You may have already faced a similar situation and I'm interested about the various ways of improvement. Thanks in advance for your reading of the situation and your potential help on this matter!

The data ingestion process is currently relying on partition switching mechanism on top of Azure SQL Server. Multiple jobs per day are running. Data is loaded into staging table, then once the data is ready, there is partition swap operation happening, taking out the previous data on this partition, replaced by the new data set. The target table is configured with a clustered columnstore index. In addition, the table is configured with the lock escalation mode set to auto.

Once the data is ingested, a monitoring system is then automatically pushing this data into some Power BI datasets in import mode, by triggering refresh at partition level in PBI. The datasets are reading data in SQL Server in a very strict way, reading data partition by partition and are never reading data that is currently being ingested into the data warehouse. This system guarantees to have always the latest data up to date in the various PBI datasets with the shortest delay possible in the end-2-end.

When the `alter table switch partition` statement is fired, it may be locked by some other running statements that are consuming data located on the same table, but on another partition. This is due to a `sch-s` lock placed by the select query on the table.

Having set the lock escalation mode to auto, I was expecting the `sch-s` lock would be placed only at partition level, but this seems not the case.

This situation is particularly annoying as the queries running on Power BI are quite long, as a lots of records need to be moved into the dataset. As Power BI is running multiple queries in parallel, the locks can remain a very long time in total, preventing ingestion of new data to complete.

Few additional notes about the current setup:

- I'm already taking advantage of the `wait_at_low_priority` feature, to ensure the swap partition process is not blocking another query to run in the meantime.
- The partition swap process has been considered as we have snapshots of data, replacing entirely was has been ingested previously for the same partition.
- Loading data in a staging table allows the computation of the columnstore index faster than inserting on the final data directly.

Here is below a test script showing the situation.
Hope this is all clear. Many thanks for your help!

- Initialization

```sql
-- Clean any previous stuff.
drop table if exists dbo.test;
drop table if exists dbo.staging_test;
drop table if exists dbo.staging_out_test;
if exists(select 1 from sys.partition_schemes where name = 'ps_test') drop partition scheme ps_test;
if exists(select 1 from sys.partition_functions where name = 'pf_test') drop partition function pf_test;
go

-- Create partition function and scheme.
create partition function pf_test (int) as range right for values(1, 2, 3);
go

create partition scheme ps_test as partition pf_test all to ([primary]);
go

alter partition scheme ps_test next used [primary];
go

-- Data table.
create table dbo.test (
    id int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
) on ps_test(id);
go

-- Staging table for data ingestion.
create table dbo.staging_test (
    id int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
) on ps_test(id);
go

-- Staging table for taking out previous data.
create table dbo.staging_out_test (
    id int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
) on ps_test(id);
go

-- Set clustered columnstore index on all tables.
create clustered columnstore index ix_test on dbo.test on ps_test(id);
create clustered columnstore index ix_staging_test on dbo.staging_test on ps_test(id);
create clustered columnstore index ix_staging_out_test on dbo.staging_out_test on ps_test(id);
go

-- Lock escalation mode is set to auto to allow locks at partition level.
alter table dbo.test set (lock_escalation = auto);
alter table dbo.staging_test set (lock_escalation = auto);
alter table dbo.staging_out_test set (lock_escalation = auto);
go

-- Insert few data...
insert into dbo.test (id, name) values(1, 'initial data partition 1'), (2, 'initial data partition 2');
insert into dbo.staging_test (id, name) values(1, 'new data partition 1'), (2, 'new data partition 2');
go

-- Display current data.
select * from dbo.test;
select * from dbo.staging_test;
select * from dbo.staging_out_test;
go
```

- Long running query example (adjust variable @c to generate more or less records):

```sql
-- Generate a long running query hitting only one specific partition on the test table.
declare @i bigint = 1;
declare @c bigint = 100000;

with x as (
    select @i n
    union all 
    select n + 1 
    from x 
    where n < @c
)

select 
    d.name
from
    x,
    (
        select name 
        from 
            dbo.test d
        where 
            d.id = 2) d
option (MaxRecursion 0)
```

- Partition swap example (to be run while "long running query" is running, showing the lock behavior:

```sql
select * from dbo.test;

-- Switch old data out.
alter table dbo.test switch partition $PARTITION.pf_test(1) to dbo.staging_out_test partition $PARTITION.pf_test(1) with(wait_at_low_priority (max_duration = 1 minutes, abort_after_wait = self));
-- Switch new data in.
alter table dbo.staging_test switch partition $PARTITION.pf_test(1) to dbo.test partition $PARTITION.pf_test(1) with(wait_at_low_priority (max_duration = 1 minutes, abort_after_wait = self));

go

select * from dbo.test;
```

Comment: A partition switch requires a schema modification lock. Although short-lived during the switch operation, this restrictive lock is at the table level, not partition level, and will be blocked by any other activity on the table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is definitely what I was concluding as well… Then… how we should design our model to suit that kind of recurring data ingestion flows with long running queries on the other hand… any idea?

Comment: You could try increasing the max_wait_time to allow time for long-running queries to finish. Your other choice is to update the table directly, with PBI queries using snapshot isolation.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely something I will consider (direct update reducing DDL operations). Thanks for your time replying to my message. Cheers.